# Show different web pages and elements depending on the user Role and Privilege

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

I have a Spring MVC web application with Thymeleaf as the template engine and Spring Security to manage the login phase.

My users can login with different Roles (ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER and ROLE_GUEST).
Moreover a user with Role ROLE_USER is part of one or more Workgroups (a set of users) and in the Workgroup he/she can act with different Privileges: WG_ADMIN, WG_USER, WG_GUEST.
Every Privilege allows the WG user to do some actions over the WG resources.

Now I have a set of views and would like to manage the authorization to the pages and elements of the pages depending on the user's Role and WG Privilege.

What is the canonical way to make things done with Spring MVC and Thymeleaf?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would require a combination of @PreAuthorize and @Secured. I will tell what is the difference. Your controller methods should be annotated with @PreAuthorize. With this, if the user does not have ROLE, user is redirected based upon your security settings.

And with @Secured, if the user does not have the ROLE, that method is not executed. So you should use @Secured in service layers.

Something like this you would required.

```
@PreAuthorize(hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN'||'ROLE_USER'))
@RequesMapping(value="/doblahblah")
public String doBlahBlahh(){
    methodOnlyAdminCanExecute();
    methodOnlyUserCanExecute();
}

@PreAuthorize(hasRole('ROLE_USER'))
@RequesMapping(value="/douserstuff")
public String douserstuff(){
    methodOnlyAdminCanExecute();
    methodOnlyUserCanExecute();
}
```

Service layer :

```
public class adminCode{

@Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
public void doAdminStuff(){
//dostuff
}

}
```

Now, even if in the 2nd controller method, this method is called, it wont execute, the @Secured annotation will be processed, and that method wont execute.

This is what I understood from your question. If this is not what you are looking for, I will delete my answer.

Comment: Thenk you, I think this is part of the solution. As for the GUI visualization of some elements in spite of others depending on the user's Role and Privilege, should I use the @GingerHead solution using the Thymeleaf's sec:authorize and sec:authentication attributes?

Comment: You can, but someone can change html, JS code from greasemonkey

Comment: So how can I prevent the user to see the administration menu items, for example? Moreover, can the configurations described at this link help me somehow? http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.7.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#authorize-requests

Comment: You cannot unless you involve backend. By retrieving it from backend is the only option. Check for the role, and then appropriately add the model.attributes of menu items. This way, even if someone manipulates the contents in front-end, its of no use.

Comment: About the link, it is just for initial configuration, nothing else. Sure, you can say, which request mapping can be accessed by who, but not that much flexibility as compared to atPreAuthorized and atSecured.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
    Hi, <span sec:authentication="principal.name"></span> 
</div>
```